# Execute $http call in angular .run() finished after controller init

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make an `$http` call in order to store a JSON into `$rootScope` in the `.run()` function in an Angular app but the call is done after the controllers are loaded and I cannot use any of the data from the call. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Also tried to see what happens with `console.log`, the output is `"b"` then `"a"` and for `$rootScope.xml` is `undefined`

```
var app = angular.module('lobby', ['ngRoute']);

app.run(['$rootScope','$http', function($rootScope, $http) {
    $http.get(Main.constants.BASEURL+'x.xml').success(function(xml) {
        $rootScope.xml = $.xml2json(xml.data);
        console.log('a');
    });
}]);

app.controller('CategoriesController', function($rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope.xml);
    console.log('b');
});
```

Comment: why not just call your `$http.get` on your controller? Either that or make a service which can return a promise that you can inject and resolve in your controller

Comment: I need this call for more than one controller I don't wanna do 10 calls for the same file, that's why I'm trying to find a way to just do one before the app loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try placing a `$watch` on `$rootScope.xml` and listen for a new value, which should occur when the `$http` call resolves & `xml` scope variable value gets changed.

**Code**

```
app.controller('CategoriesController', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$watch('xml', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if($rootScope.xml) {
            console.log($rootScope.xml);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a step forward but I still have an issue, now in console.log I get b, undefined, a and then the object. I need to get rid of the undefined case because if I try to use the object I get an error that crashes angular.js

Comment: see edit, you have `oldValue` and `newValue` as well to eliminate an `undefined` situation

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, I've filtered it with $.type